# Mocking a RestTemplate in Spring

Tags: junit, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to test my spring rest client but I am having trouble. Here is my client class:

```java
@Component
public class MyClient{    

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;


    @Autowired
    public MyClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,ResponseErrorHandler myResponseErrorHandler) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                .errorHandler(myResponseErrorHandler)
                .build();
    }
    //other codes here
}
```

here `myResponseErrorHandler`  is class that overrides  `handleError` and `hasError` methods of `ResponseErrorHandler` class.

Now my test class is as

```java
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class MyClientTest {    

        @InjectMocks
        MyClient myClient;
        @Mock
        RestTemplate restTemplate;
        @Mock
        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

       //test cases here
    }
```

But I am getting an error as below and I am not sure how to fix this.

```
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : null
```

Answer (score 5):

That problem is because when you run your app normally, Spring Boot configures `RestTemplateBuilder` for you automatically (because of `@SpringBootApplication` annotation), but in your test you don't have corresponding `@SpringBootTest` annotation, and `restTemplateBuilder` in MyClient's constructor is of course null (which produces your error while trying to call build() method on it).

If you add it as is, it would use the app default configuration context, and both `RestTemplateBuilder` and `MyResponseErrorHandler` would be working beans (Note that in that case both `MyClient` and `MyResponseErrorHandler` should've been configured as beans - f.e. by marking them with `@Component`).

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyClientTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyClient myClient;

    @Mock
    private MyResponseErrorHandler myResponseErrorHandler;

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws IOException {
        //The example of configuring myResponseErrorHandler behavior
        Mockito.when(myResponseErrorHandler.hasError(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true);

        //Call myClient method

        //Asserts...
    }
}
```

Also, don't do anything with `RestTemplate`, because it would be created programmatically inside MyClient constructor.

**Another approach** is to create a separate test configuration, where you can get the default `RestTemplateBuilder` bean (provided by Spring) and mocked `MyResponseErrorHandler` (for configuring its behavior later). It could give you the full control of how to configure all of your beans for tests without using your app context.

If you want to dig into it - here are the steps to achieve this:

1. Create test configuration class with `MyResponseErrorHandler` bean:

```java
@TestConfiguration
public class MyClientTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder;

    @Bean
    public ResponseErrorHandler myResponseErrorHandler() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyResponseErrorHandler.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public MyClient myClient() {
        return new MyClient(restTemplateBuilder, myResponseErrorHandler());
    }
}
```

2. Your test class would be like this:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyClientTestConfiguration.class)
public class MyClientTest {

    @Autowired //wired from MyClientTestConfiguration class
    private MyClient myClient;

    @Autowired //wired from MyClientTestConfiguration class
    private MyResponseErrorHandler myResponseErrorHandler; 

    @Test
    public void sampleTest() throws IOException {
        //The example of configuring myResponseErrorHandler behavior
        Mockito.when(myResponseErrorHandler.hasError(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(true);

        //Calling myClient method...

        //Asserts...
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create separate config for test cases and your first approach is not working giving null point exception.

Comment: Have you annotated MyResponseErrorHandler and MyClient with @Component? Also, you'd better upload your sample project on Github and post a link instead of giving mostly useless comments like "it's not working", "i don't think this will work", "that's not helping" etc. In fact, all 3 answers here could help to fix your problem.

Comment: Btw I've created the sample working project too which absolutely corresponds to your question. You can check it. https://github.com/amseager/myclient

Comment: First of all I can't share my company's code on github. Second you are not mocking and getting a real instance of myClient. Now my test case will no more be test and they will do real thing. My test case will save data to database ?? Not happy with this approach.

Comment: restTemplate is the private field which is configured inside the constructor. Mocking private fields is possible using some libs like PowerMockito, but in your case, it will always lead to have 2 instances of restTemplate (one is mocked and one is built inside the constructor), which will obviously useless. BUT you can affect on constructing the desired restTemplate by providing mocked MyClient constructor properties (so myClient ceases to be real).

Comment: I gave an example of how to do it with MyResponseErrorHandler. You can also do the same with RestTemplateBuilder, but in that case, you would need to implement almost all its building logic with when..then.., otherwise it will lead to get NPEs while calling, f.e., build() method (remember that all methods of mocked object return null/default values if you don't change its behavior). If you're able to implement a whole bunch of RestTemplateBuilder methods - lotsa luck. I'd better refactor that code to make it more testable.

Comment: refactor code ? i think there is nothing i can refactor. Any way thanks for your time but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have a good [example](https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/) for mocking autowired service with dependencies,

In your case you need to mock also `ResponseErrorHandler`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClientTest {

@Mock
private ResponseErrorHandler responseErrorHandler ;

@Mock
private RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder ;

private MyClient myClient;

@Before
void setUp() {
    myClient = new MyClient(restTemplateBuilder ,responseErrorHandler );
}
```

Comment: That part i was able to do. But it will fail as soon as it hits constructor with two mocked parameters. I tried when .... then... that is not helping.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
public class MyClient{    

private RestTemplate restTemplate;


@Autowired
public MyClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder,ResponseErrorHandler myResponseErrorHandler) {
    this(restTemplateBuilder
            .errorHandler(myResponseErrorHandler)
            .build());
}

MyClient(RestTemplate template) {
    this.restTemplate = template;
}
//other codes here
}
```

This example below is when running normally. Modify to use `SpringRunner.class`.

public class MyClientTest {

```
   private MyClient myClient;
   @Mock private RestTemplate restTemplate;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       myClient = new MyClient(restTemplate);
   }

   //test cases here
}
```

Comment: i am not sure why you have two different constructor.

Comment: testability. Your system under test works with `RestTemplate` or with `RestTemplateBuilder` and `ResponseErrorHandler`?